# Verifying that a save was called in a Service Test

Tags: grails, testing, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 2.4 and I have a helper service that creates a specific domain class, sets up the dependencies surrounding it and then finally saves the object to the database, within a promise.

How would I test this service?

An example of the service is:

```
def persist(name, objectId, depTwoId) {
  Person p = Person.findByName(name)
  Object o = Object.findById(objectId)

  RepObject rob = RepObject(p, o) //Ok you get the idea here

  def task = Promises.task { 
     rob.save()
  } 
}
```

I don't care, within the context of the unit test, if there was a save to the database. I just want to know that it was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do something to wait for the async call to finish, but that's a separate issue.

I'd do it with the metaclass if all you want to verify is that save is called, but not that the object is actually persisted:

Before you call the `persist` method in your integration test, add this:

```
boolean saveCalled = false
RepObject.metaClass.save = { -> saveCalled = true }
```

and in your Spock `then` block or wherever you do verification calls, add

```
assert saveCalled
```

Note that the signature of the metaclass `save` closure has to match what's actually called. You show it being called with no args, but if you call `save(flush:true)` then you're passing a Map arg and the signature would have to be

```
RepObject.metaClass.save = { Map m -> saveCalled = true }
```

otherwise Groovy won't choose yours, it will call the real method.

Comment: You'll have to overwite the Promise as well. 
Promises.metaClass.static.task = { Closure closure -> closure() }

Comment: Yep, that's a good way to convert it to a synchronous call to make testing simpler.

Comment: Thanks! I'm finding that you and Scott with the Grails team have been freaking phenomenal with answering questions!

Comment: That would be Jeff, Scott's his middle name :)

Comment: Thats the guy! Anyways, you guys are awesome!